# RCP E4 Statusbar is to small

Tags: swt, rcp, e4

I create a statusbar for my e4 rcp application but the statusbar is to small.

In my Appliication.e4xmi is the following configured:

Trimmed Window -> TrimBars -> Window Trim (Bottom) -> Toolbar -> Tool Control (link to my StatusBar class)

Linked StatusBar class:

```
public class StatusBar {

private Label label;

@Inject
private IEventBroker eventBroker;
public static final String STATUSBAR = "statusbar";

@Inject
@Optional
public void getEvent(@UIEventTopic(STATUSBAR) String message) {
    updateInterface(message);
}

@PostConstruct
public void createControls(Composite parent) {
    label = new Label(parent, SWT.LEFT);
    label.setBackground(parent.getBackground());
}

public void updateInterface(String message) {
    try {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    label.setText(message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.fillInStackTrace());
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error(exception.fillInStackTrace());
    }
}
```

[View of the Statusbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1oYs.png)

Comment: Too small in what way? Not deep enough? Not long enough?

Comment: The height of the statusbar is to small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `Toolbar` for a `ToolControl`. Put the ToolControl as the immediate child of the Trim Bar.

Put the label in a composite to get it layed out properly:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void createGui(final Composite parent)
{
  Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

  body.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  Label label = new Label(body, SWT.LEFT);

  label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

   ....
}
```

You may also want to specify a tag value of `stretch` in ToolControl definiton in the e4xmi to make the control use all available horizontal space in the trim bar.

Comment: This doesn't work and if i define a LayoutData on the body, the statusbar has the correct height but i get a classcastexecption:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData

Comment: I missed that  you were putting the ToolControl in a Toolbar - you don't need to do that. Put the ToolControl as the child of the Trim Bar, no Toolbar required.